# Dont let me mount

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, fstab

First of all... Good day. I'm a Linux User from very long time and I love it. So much sometimes I make "experiments" And things broke up without knowing exactly why.
This Time I try to move the /home and /usr to dedícate partitions into another HDD (because my SSD was getting full) I think I made all like it's suposed to be. I copy all the /home and /usr into their final destination, (first I think without SUDO so... Maybe that's a key to the problem, but later I overwrite with Root so...) I edit FSTAB, I back-upped and, later cleared the originals (so the FSTAB could find an empty canvas  I only made it without /Home) and reset. All kinda good except... There's no /usr. Wha? IT was that I made a misstake in FSTAB. I fix IT and worked. (Maybe there is another key todo the issue) all good except... I cannot mount any drive. Dont let me. Say I don't have the needed permissions. Also fails on the update manager and logout window lacks of any buttons except the "cancel" One. I'm kinda lost. Help. I will Be happy answering any doubts you have. Maybe I left some importante detalles. Thank you in advance

Comment: This is a useful reference to moving your home directory when you get to that stage.

Comment: Besides my issue xD thanks. Maybe other day I'll make a full tutorial. I certainly  left away importante details

Comment: You have stirred your system with a `root` stick  without even trying to understand what `/home` and `/usr` were, how they were used, what parts of the system used them, or how Linux works. All I can say is reinstall, don't do that.